# Only grab some innertext from a SelectNode with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I've been using HtmlAgilityPack in order to parse some html in a web page. The current html looks like this:

```
div class="price__child price__price flex-child__auto tooltip-container">
                                    <div class="price__min-order tooltip-container js-minOrder">
                                        <i>⚠️</i>
                                        <div class="price__min-order-tooltip tooltip">
                                            Minimum order of $15.00.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                $1.75
                        </div>
```

I only want to retrieve the text of the price at the very end, in this case, the `$1.75`. Doing something like below will return that number, but also the all of the other text within the larger div.

```
return node
                .SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'price__child price__price')]")
                .InnerText
                .Trim().Replace(" ", "")
                .TrimStart('$');
```

Is there a way to exclude/not grab the innertext from the `price__min-order tooltip-container js-minOrder` and also the `price__min-order-tooltip tooltip`, and only grab the `1.75` from the larger div?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it. If you call child node and remove, it will get rid of it.

```
var priceNode = node
                .SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'price__child price__price')]")
                ?.ChildNodes[1];
            priceNode?.Remove();

            return node
                .SelectSingleNode(".//div[contains(@class, 'price__child price__price')]")
                .InnerText
                .Trim().Replace(" ", "")
                .TrimStart('$');
```